# Too much data was sent during this period and being removed in Application Insights

Tags: azure, azure-application-insights

When logging using Application Insight I get the following Trace message "Too much data was sent during this period and being removed for debugger responsiveness."

I would really like to see all the data (its 22 log entries in total, where about 8 is displayed and the rest is removed)

Any idea on how to configure this?

Comment: What application/service are you logging from?

Comment: If you see the message from visual studio, one possibility is that the visual studio has some limit to show all the messages(if it's large) and all the messages can be displayed on app insights on azure portal. Otherwise, you should follow Murray's method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to disable [sampling](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/azure-monitor/app/sampling) in order to record all logs from with Application insights.

For example, if you are using ASP.NET Core you can configure sampling as per the below snippet from the docs.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
// ...

var aiOptions = new Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore.Extensions.ApplicationInsightsServiceOptions();
aiOptions.EnableAdaptiveSampling = false;
services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry(aiOptions);

//...
}
```

Keep in mind that App Insights has a maximum retention period of 90 days.

If you are experiencing the "Too much data was sent during this period and being removed for debugger responsiveness" message in Visual Studio, look at [this thread](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/8557). In short, it says you can (to a degree) configure Visual Studio to show more data before it starts to filter out messages. However, it is not a good idea to play with these settings, and if you have high volumes of logs to inspect (either large entries and/or many entries), you should be doing this through the Application Insights user web interface, which (as long as sampling is configured off), will have persisted all the logs entries.

Quote below:

> That "Too much data" message occurs only in VS (it doesn't affect what
>   data gets *sent* by the sdks), and is triggered if we see debugger
>   output that was too big for us to "comfortably" process without
>   slowing down the debugger.
>
> Basically, the debugger batches up output window messages, and
>   processes them. if we see really big ones, we do simple contains
>   checks instead of regular expression checks on them. if that block of
>   text contained any ai messages that we would have to parse out, and
>   was huge (default is 20k characters), we skip processing it (we have
>   to find every event in the giant chunk, parse each event, etc) and
>   instead show that message; to save debugger time, we just skip the
>   whole batch and add the note that there *was* telemetry (you can see
>   it in the output window, it will get sent by the sdk), but the
>   debugger tools didn't waste time parsing it all.
>
> there's a way to change the values we use as thresholds in the
>   debugger, but they will end up making your VS experience slower as
>   we'd spend a lot more time parsing events in the output window. if
>   you've identified what it is (one giant EF query) i'm not sure if you
>   want to change the settings to make us parse that to show it to you.

Comment: I think the original issue is about local visual studio session limits, not the actual ai backend limits.

Comment: Quite possibly. Force of habit, I go straight to the portal

Comment: Added a block to the answer w.r.t. the Visual Studio issue,

Answer (score 1):

You can increase the default limit of 20000 characters:

1. Close all VS instances.
2. Execute `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\VsRegEdit.exe" set "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise" HKCU AppInsightsGettingStarted MessageTooLongLength dword 40000`